# Is there any way to use ROS on Window with Python3?

Tags: python, ros

I am using python3 to use PyQt5 and opencv.
and using Python2 with ROS on Window.
I want to use both ROS and PyQt5 on Window with Python3.
So I should know how to use ROS with Python3 on Window.
Any Idea??
I'd appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python3 is targeted on ROS only for the latest release, Noetic. If you’d like to use Python3 you should install Noetic, if you’re doing it on windows it’s possible to get it working by following the steps here: http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows

That being said, Ubuntu 20.04 is the OS Noetic is targeted towards so any Windows builds can have varying levels of stability. The more correct answer here, if you want to use Python3 on Windows, is to use ROS2; both Python3 and Windows are targeted for the ROS2 Foxy release.

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks.